# why is the call and apply function used instead of just invoking it directly

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is a piece from the jQuery library. 
Notice how the `flat` function is used with the `call` and the context as the `array` which is passed.

```
var arr = [];

var getProto = Object.getPrototypeOf;

var slice = arr.slice;

var flat = arr.flat ? function( array ) {
    return arr.flat.call( array );
} : function( array ) {
    return arr.concat.apply( [], array );
};
```

So, what is the use of doing this instead of just `array.flat()` since we don't need to attach any other context or parameters to it.

I have the same question with the `apply` function right below it. It works as same as `[].concat(array)`

Comment: `array` is most likely only array-like but not a real array.

Comment: My guess would be to handle `array` not actually being an array.

Comment: okay, if it is so, then why use apply for the concat.

Comment: @SRINATHBasker again, it's not an array. And if the current environment doesn't support `flat`, then it will fall back to `concat`.

Comment: "*It works as same as `[].concat(array)`*" - no, it doesn't. It works the same as `[].concat(...array)`, but doesn't use spread syntax.

Comment: @Bergi  you may try with both the cases. I saw no difference with or without spread. `[2].concat([3,4,5,6])` gives `[ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]` so does `[2].concat(...[3,4,5,6])`

Comment: @SRINATHBasker try `[].concat( [[1], [2], [3]] )` and `[].concat( ...[[1], [2], [3]] )` or `[].concat.apply([],  [[1], [2], [3]] )`

Comment: Spread syntax will not work in older browsers and jQuery is famously compatible with most things. You cannot call `arr.concat(...array)` without errors, hence you'd use `apply` as a workaround.

Comment: @SRINATHBasker `array` is expected to be an array of arrays - that's what they're writing the `flat` function for.